# Split huge traffic data into multiple database VS multiple table/collection for mysql/mongodb

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, database

I am developing a PHP Web service HTTP GET API which write and read data to/from a database database like MySQL/MongoDB. It has 3 SELECT/find() queries and 2 INSERT queries to a single table/collection

It is called about 10,000 times per second asynchronously by different clients.

I am planing to split the data to multiple table according to the user name start letter. I mean if a user name start with D demouser, then system will store the data to table_d/collection-d and so on. This is option 1

### OPTION 1

same database multiple table/collection

```
DATABASE-table_a/collection-a
         table_b/collection-b
         table_c/collection-c
```

OPTION 2

multiple database with single table/collection

```
DATABASE-a  table
DATABASE-b  table
DATABASE-c  table
```

please advice me which is best way to increse the speed? thank you for your help

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to use MongoDB's Sharding functionality - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-introduction/  This will let you split your data cross multiple MongoD instances using the username as the shard key

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you for your reply. I am not going to use multiple server. I am currently using single server with Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v3 Hexa-Core,
256 GB DDR4 ECC RAM 2 x 480 GB 6 Gb/s SSD (Software-RAID-1). So, you mean OPTION 2 is best?